# Sum the fields whose tables are in join clause but are not in group clause

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, group-by, left-join

I want to convert this query to Linq. I left joined BLTb to BMTb and CbTb. I did not use BLTb  in group by clause. I can't convert this query to Linq because I can't sum BLTb.IsAprv. I just can sum the fields whose tables are in group by clause in linq.

Could someone please tell me how I can convert the below query to Linq.

Note:
"BLTb.BLCod" is not the PK of the table  "BLTb".
"BMTb.Id" is not the PK of the table " BMTb"

```
SELECT     BMTb.BCod, CBTb.CmCod, 
CASE WHEN   
    SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(BMTb.IsAprv, 0) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    SUM(CASE WHEN BLTb.IsAprv = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    > 0 then 0 else 1 end AS IsAprv
FROM BMTb 
INNER JOIN CBTb ON BMTb.CBCod = CBTb.CBCod 
LEFT OUTER JOIN BLTb ON BMTb.Id = BLTb.BLCod
GROUP BY  BCod
```

Linq:

```
var BMTb = (from m in db.BMTbs.AsQueryable()
                            select new
                            {
                                isAprove=m.IsAprv==null?1:m.IsAprv==false?1:0,
                                m.CBCod,
                               m.IsAprv,
                               m.BCod,
                               m.Id
                            }
                            );
        var BLTb = (from l in db.BLTbs.AsQueryable()
                            select new
                            {
                                l.BMCod,
                               isAprove= l.IsAprv==false?1:0

                            }
                            );


        var AproveCB = (from m in BMTb.AsQueryable()
                           join c in db.CBTbs.AsQueryable() on m.CBCod equals c.CBCod
                           join l in BLTb.AsQueryable() on m.Id equals l.BMCod into lL
                           from lLeft in lL.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           group new { m, c } by new {m.BCod,c. CmCod, }
                           into grp
                           select new
                           {
                               sum1=grp.Sum(gp=>gp.m.isAprove)/*+grp.Sum(gp => gp.isAprove) */> 0?0:1,
                               BCod=grp.Key.BCod,
                               CmCod=grp.Key.CmCod,


                           }
                           );
```

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Comment: Your grouping by `BCod` but your `SELECT` has a reference to `CBTb.CmCod` - how is that legal in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straight forward translation of the SQL to Linq:

```
var ans = from b in BMTb
          join c in CBTb on b.CBCod equals c.CBCod
          join l in BLTb on b.Id equals l.Id into lj
          from l in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
          group new { bIsAprv = b.IsAprv, c.CmCod, lIsAprv = l.IsAprv } by b.BCod into bclg
          select new {
              BCod = bclg.Key,
              bclg.First().CmCod,
              IsAprv = (bclg.Sum(bcl => bcl.bIsAprv == null ? 1 : 0)+bclg.Sum(bcl => bcl.lIsAprv == 0 ? 1 : 0) > 0) ? 0 : 1
          };
```

I used `First()` to pull out one `CmCod` from the groups, I don't believe the SQL is legal. I am also unsure how you can test `BLTb.IsAprv` when you are left joining with `BLTb` so it might be null.